# Append a DataFrame as a row to a larger DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have an empty dataframe (data) that I definied as follows:

```
 data=pd.DataFrame({'A':[],'B':[],'C':[],'D':[]})
```

and by means of a for loop I am obtaining several temporary dataframes that look like this:

```
index   order_count
 C             3
 A             1
 B             1
```

I would like to populate "data" by using the data these temporary dataframes.    I guess I would have to check for the "order_count" column into the "index" and add the corresponding "order_count". After that, perhaps concatenate the temporary results.

I would like to obtain the following output for "data":

```
time_interval   A  B  C  D
     1          1  1  3  0
     2          1  1  1  1
    ...
```

Comment: Please show your expected output, don't just describe it.

Comment: Yes, I have provided more details about the type of output.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I've written an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `append` which returns a copy (relatively inefficient when calling append multiple times):

```
data

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []

temp_df

  index  order_count
0     C            3
1     A            1
2     B            1
```

```
data.append(temp_df.set_index('index')['order_count'], ignore_index=True)

     A    B    C   D
0  1.0  1.0  3.0 NaN
```

Another option is in-place assignment with loc:

```
data.loc[len(df),:] = temp_df.set_index('index')['order_count']
data

     A    B    C   D
4  1.0  1.0  3.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've well understood your problem, I guess this could do the trick :

```
#df being the dataFrame and temp being the one you are wellling to add
df = df.append(temp.set_index('index').T, ignore_index = True)
```